# Can't post to https using httpwebrequest

Tags: c#, https, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to leverage functions that have already been done in one part of our website by logging into that website and then interacting with it like I was at a browser. There may be a better approach altogether, so that would be welcome. I'm constrained to using C#, though.

This form in an otherwise empty webpage successfully logs into the website (which I, of course, fictionalized):

```
        <input id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" type="text" value="theprocess@oursite.com" />
       <input id="Password" name="Password" type="password" value="avalidpassword" />
         <button type="submit" >Log in</button>
```

I've tried this with no success. It just keeps reloading the same login page.

```
             var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://oursite.com/Admin/Account/Login");

            string postData = "EmailAddress=theprocess@oursite.com";
            postData += "&Password=avalidpassword";
            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);


            request.Method = "POST";
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = data.Length;

            using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
            }

            var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();


            var responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

I've also tried this:

```
        string URI = "https://myaccount.boom.us/Admin/Account/Login";
            string postData = "EmailAddress=theprocess@oursite.com";
            postData += "&Password=avalidpassword";

        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            string HtmlResult = wc.UploadString(URI, postData);
        }
```

And it, too, just reloads the same login page.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Best way to debug this is to use a tool like Fiddler and login your site via browser. inspect the request that is sent to the server and compare it to the one you are sending in your code and see what is missing.

Comment: I tried fiddler, but it doesn't give any useful information. Or maybe I am not proficient enough to extract useful information from fiddler.